# How to return a specific type from a method overriding a method from parent abstract class, using generics?

Tags: java, generics

I have a generic tree

```
public abstract class Tree<T extends Term, U extends Terms>{
    protected T           termA;
    protected U           termB;
    protected Tree<T,U>[] childs;

    protected Tree( final T termA, final U termB, final Tree<T,U>[] childs){
        this.termA = termA;
        this.termB = termB;
    }

    public T getTermA(){
        return termA;
    }

    public U getTermB(){
        return termB;
    }

    public Tree<T,U>[] getChilds(){
        return childs;
    }
}


public final class TreeImpl extends Tree<Boolean,String>{
    public TreeImpl( final Boolean termA, final String termB,TreeImpl[] childs){
        super( termA, termB, childs);
    }
}
```

In this case TreeImpl.getChilds return Tree[]. I would like to know if hiding methods as

```
public TreeImpl[] getChilds(){
        return childs;
}
```

is it the best way to do?

Thanks

Comment: Could you elaborate? What are you trying to access?

Comment: Arrays won't do nicely with generics, you can try to use a list instead. And give more details on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: best way to do *what*?